# Insert a formula for specific cells

Tags: excel, vba

Due to beginner for VBA, I am in a difficult to find this codes. I need to create 'Command Button' to insert formula according to current cell location.
example: 
I have these cells that has data C3, C5, C10 so as you can see the C4, C6, C7, C8, C9, C11, C12, C13 has no data so here is the thing that the result I want.

So for C4 I wanted to get the data in C3

in C6, C7, C8, C9 I wanted to get the data in C5

in C11, C12, C13 I wanted to get the data for C10.

after copying the data in empty cells the C3 C5 and C10 will be deleted(row).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO. Even if you are a newbie, you should at least post the code you've tried.

Anyways, this code will do what you want:

```
Dim rng As Range

'copy text
For Each rng In Range("C3:C13")
    If rng.Value = "" Then rng.Value = rng.Offset(-1, 0).Value
Next rng

'delete rows
Set rng = Union(Rows("3:3"), Rows("5:5"), Rows("10:10"))
rng.EntireRow.Delete
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Sub test()

    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range, rngDelete As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Set rng1 = .Range("C4")
        Set rng2 = Union(.Range("C6"), .Range("C7"), .Range("C8"), .Range("C9"))
        Set rng3 = Union(.Range("C11"), .Range("C12"), .Range("C13"))
        Set rngDelete = Union(.Range("C3"), .Range("C5"), .Range("C10"))

        rng1.Value = .Range("C3").Value
        rng2.Value = .Range("C5").Value
        rng3.Value = .Range("C10").Value

        rngDelete.EntireRow.Delete

    End With

End Su
```